# May I have an event which repeats monthly to an undetermined end wit react-big-calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, repeat, react-big-calendar

I am using the react-big-calendar and I would like to have some sort of event which repeats each month to an undetermined end... i.e. I would write the start end for the event and then it will every month be displayed on the screen.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

React-Big-Calendar displays the `events` you give it, through the `events` prop. You would have to manually replicate the repeated items and add them to your `events` array at the proper intervals.